# AngularJs обработка input

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Здравствуйте.

Передо мной стоит задача отсеивать студентов с именами, которые не подходят тому, что я ввожу в input. Т.е. если я начинаю вводить имя на букву "В", то все "Алексеи" отсеиваются и т.д. Когда я начинаю вводить имя в input, то вылазит ошибка, мол `.length` переменной `text` (куда записываются всё из input) `undefined`. И дальше по мере ввода ничего не меняется и не работает. Подскажите в чём проблема?

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('app', []);
  app.controller('DataController', function() {
    this.students = gems;
    this.compare = function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.text.length; i++) {
        if (this.text[i] == this.students.name[i]) {
          alert(this.text);
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
  });
  var gems = [{
    name: 'Azurite',
    price: 2.95
  }, {
    name: 'Bloodstone',
    price: 5.95
  }, {
    name: 'Zircon',
    price: 3.95
  }];
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <input class="col-md-12 col-xs-12" type="text" placeholder="Search people by name..." ng-model='text' ng-change='data.students.name'>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="btn btn-sort">Sort by name</button>
      <button class="btn btn-sort">Sort by age</button>
      <button ng-click='data.click()' class="btn btn-danger">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--Main content-->
  <div class="main-table col-sm-8  col-md-7 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-7 col-lg-offset-1">
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="text-center">Image</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Phone</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody ng-repeat='student in data.students' ng-show='data.compare()'>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <img src="/img/cat.svg" alt="">
          </td>
          <td>{{student.name}}</td>
          <td>41</td>
          <td>sieg@example.com</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Можно предложить вариант на Jquery?

Comment: Давайте. Я хоть и на знаю jquery, но на логику посмотрю.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю своё решение на чистом JavaScript:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('name');

input.onkeyup = function() {
  var tr = document.querySelectorAll('.table tbody tr');
  for(var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++){
    // Создаём регулярное выражение: строка должна начинаться со значения указанного в input
    var regexp = new RegExp('^'+this.value.toLowerCase()+'.*$', 'i');
    // Проверяем, начинается ли она со значения указанного в input
    if(regexp.exec(tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[1].innerHTML.toLowerCase())){ // toLowerCase() нежно, что бы воспринимало любой регистр
      tr[i].style.display = 'table-row'; // Показываем соответствующие строки
    }else{
      tr[i].style.display = 'none'; // Скрываем строки, которые не подходят
    };
  };
};
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">Image</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody ng-repeat='student in data.students' ng-show='data.compare()'>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZsJn.jpg?s=32&g=1" alt="">
      </td>
      <td>Юрий</td>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>yurka_mail@ukr.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6a2ebc4c3e8238a0f205e9cf32e4fb92?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="">
      </td>
      <td>Александр</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>sieg@example.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8ae54a5fe67401eabebeff0a86d82dba?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="">
      </td>
      <td>Иван</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>sieg@example.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/026c32d1335230193ba501286b809d5c?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="">
      </td>
      <td>Василий</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>sieg@example.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2a246ffd14ebccdbee907e96647eee52?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="">
      </td>
      <td>Виктор</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>sieg@example.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<p>
  <div>Введите имя:</div>
  <input type="text" id="name">
</p>
```